# How to add a white space between function name and open bracket in VS Code

Tags: javascript, editor, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

In the JavaScript editor of Visual Studio Code, I would like to add a white space between the function name and the open bracket (when `function` is defined).

```
function name ()   // <- whitespace before brackets
{
   ...
}
```

But when I press `[Enter]` the white space is automatically removed.

Is it possible to keep it (or to auto-instert one white space), without disabling the auto-formatter?

I know I can use `[Ctrk + Z]` to remove the last auto-formatting but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: It should. Maybe try following [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace) to change VSCode settings. In the editor on the right, just add to the bottom `"typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true`

Comment: @Acidic I know but I've already done that and whether is it true or false changes nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `settings.json` and format the file using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true
```

Or set it in settings menu

[image]

Works in VSCode 1.64

Answer (score 1):

```
function name () {
    ...
}
```

Is this code you need? Just use the shortcut: `Shift + Alt + F`

Comment: Is your vscode version the latest? I've tested it in my vscode and it works well.

Comment: It's version 1.9.1, and for me this removes the white spaces before the open brackets.